# with Networkx, how to write graphml and other format into a string, instead of a file?

Tags: python, networkx, graphml

I'm using networkx very superficially. It's easy to write a graph to a file, like graphml, but how can I save it into a string without bothering the file system?

[Its doc](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html#networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml) says it is possible.

Comment: This should be possible using `StringIO`.

Comment: Is there anyway I can reverse this process? i.e, build graph from string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the formats also have a "generator".  So you can do it this way without using StringIO:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.path_graph(4)

In [3]: s='\n'.join(nx.generate_graphml(G))

In [4]: print s
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key attr.name="name" attr.type="string" for="graph" id="d0" />
  <graph edgedefault="undirected">
    <data key="d0">path_graph(4)</data>
    <node id="0" />
    <node id="1" />
    <node id="2" />
    <node id="3" />
    <edge source="0" target="1" />
    <edge source="1" target="2" />
    <edge source="2" target="3" />
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Comment: I browsed the source just after posting my answer, saw the generator call, but I just did not see that solution. +1

Answer (score 5):

Just as larsmans commented, it's possible using [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html):

```
import networkx as nx
import StringIO
import itertools

g = nx.Graph()

edges = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2)
g.add_edges_from(edges)

# File-like object
output = StringIO.StringIO()

nx.write_graphml(g, output)

# And here's your string
gstr = output.getvalue()
print gstr
output.close()
```

Comment: Did you try running this? It fails because of an empty graph; when you fix that, `getvalue()` fails because the pseudo-file is closed after `write_graphml` finishes.

Comment: Yes, I tried to run it. The "add nodes and edges" was just for illustration purposes, and `getvalue()` works fine for me. My update is the exact thing that I run.

Comment: Turns out I'm running an outdated networkx version and they fixed this in the meantime. +1 to you.